# JDBC SQL Server Exception while setting up WSO2 API Manager 2.2 with SQL Server Express

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am configuring a SQL Server Express database as mentioned in the [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+MSSQL)

The master-datasources.xml file has been appropriately changed. However, when I try to start the WSO2 API-M 2.2 server (<*PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/wso2server.bat -Dsetup), I am getting the following exception -

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, named instance \new_instance_exp failed.
>   Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:5247)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1871)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1608)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:58)
>           ... 20 more

I have verified that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

Note: The APIM databases I am creating are not on the default instance (which use the the default port 1433). I have created a new instance in the same SQL Server with a custom port and I have configured the settings for TCP and Named Pipes (disabled) in the SQL Configuration Manager.

I am using the recommended SQL driver (sqljdbc4) as mentioned in this link - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL

Comment: Is that port accessible from the APIM VM ? You can telnet and see.

Comment: Yes @Bee, I am able to TELNET on the specific port.